# A quote from 星の王子様 (The Little Prince)

Tags: reading-comprehension

There is a popular quote from the famous novel *The Little Prince*:

> What is essential is invisible to the eye.

The Japanese translation goes something like this:

> 大切な物は目に見えないんだ。

I have three questions:
First, invisible is "cannot be seen". Why is 見えない used instead of 見られない？

Second, what does it mean when you put: んだ in the end of the sentence? For me i wouldnt have thought about it and could have ended with みられない。

Third, 大切 is important. Since the word used in the text is essential, is it possible that there is a better word for that? Something that is one level higher than just being important? Perhaps a level like 欠かせない。

Comment: First question http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19022/11104

Comment: Second question http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23936/11104

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q1**: Because the verb 見える has [more than one meaning](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210883/meaning/m0u/), and it can both mean "to be able to see (something)" and "to be visible". See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21516/5010), too.

**Q2**: んだ is a colloquial form of のだ. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23936/5010).

**Q3**: Literally, *important* is 大切/重要 and *essential* is 本質的. And according to [this page](http://ijustat.com/gaikokugo/le_petit_prince/01.html), the original French version seems to contain two similar sentences, one using *essentiel* and one using *important*:

> - **L'essentiel** est invisible pour les yeux.
> - Le plus **important** est invisible.

The translation of the latter using *important* seems to be better-known in Japan. 「本質的なものは目に見えない」 would perfectly make sense, but the word 本質的 may be a bit too difficult for children.